# How does SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync work?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In a project im working on I found the following:

```
// GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
{
   var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
   if(await RegisterUser(info))
   {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
   }
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
}
```

It's called after an OAUTH login redirect. SignInManager is from namespace:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```

The description of GetExternalLoginInfoAsync:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets the external login information for the current login, as an asynchronous
//     operation.
//
// Parameters:
//   expectedXsrf:
//     Flag indication whether a Cross Site Request Forgery token was expected in the
//     current request.
//
// Returns:
//     The task object representing the asynchronous operation containing the ExternalLoginInfo
//     for the sign-in attempt.
```

Oke so it gets external login information for the current login as an asynchronous operation, I get that. But how does it work? is it based on request data, does it search for a specific part in the request data, do I need to specify some settings for it to work? I tried googling many variations but cant find info on how to use it or how it works (does it expect me to do anything?).

*note : the code works fine but I try to understand what it does and how.*

Comment: The code for [Identity is on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/src/Identity), so you could take a look there.